# How do I import refinerycms layouts into a custom controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, refinerycms

I'm trying to add the refinerycms application layout to a custom controller ie,

```
layout 'application'
```

but I get the error

```
undefined method `browser_title' for nil:NilClass


Extracted source (around line #4):

1: <head>
2:   <meta charset='<%= ::Refinery::Application.config.encoding %>' />
3:   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
4:   <title><%= browser_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
5:   <%= raw "<meta name=\"description\" content=\"#{@meta.meta_description}\" />" if @meta.meta_description.present? -%>
6:   <%= raw "<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"#{@meta.meta_keywords}\">" if @meta.meta_keywords.present? -%>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tag if RefinerySetting.find_or_set(:authenticity_token_on_frontend, true)-%>
```

How do I import the refinery layout into a custom controller?

Comment: I think you did it well, but you need `<% content_for :title do %>  Title <% end %>` in your views

Comment: What do you mean? Where would I put that?

Comment: as I wrote before, add it to the views of your new controller.

Comment: Ah, I realised that I had overridden _head.html.erb, which I thought was hidden in the gem, so I wasn't sure what file it was in. But even with changing the title line, there were errors elsewhere in the template. I opted for doing things the other way around (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255846/how-do-i-import-refinerycms-layouts-into-a-custom-controller/6278090#6278090)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing things the other way around, and overriding the pages controller with my custom controller logic (from [this](http://groups.google.com/group/refinery-cms/browse_thread/thread/f679f70fffb32bd8/2965b8607e084eba?lnk=gst&q=custom%20controller#2965b8607e084eba)), instead of including the refinery cms layout in my custom controller. This included the right layout, so I didn't get the error anymore.